# How do I test string data type in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation, comparison, string-length

I want to test string type in VB.NET, for example. A number plate follows the format 2 letters, 2 numbers, 3 letters.

I want to take the input from a user and by using an `if` statement I want to check if the format is correct. If it is not, then I want to store it under a variable or output it depending on if they are speeding (my program). How would I check for a certain amount of numbers and letters in a string?

Comment: Take a look at [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This sort of thing becomes trivial using them.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the [Like Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx). Something like this should do it:

```
    If TextBox1.Text Like "??##???" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Store the value - it was in the correct format", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Input format incorrect", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
    End If
```

Comment: ++ i have forgotten the wonderful Like-operator (too much C#).

Comment: Thank you, but how can i get it so that I can then compare it to my previous criteria (My program is a speed limit checker, if the regplate is irregular and the speed is over the speed limit then both will be outputted). Instead of displaying a message box I want to store it to a specific variable.

Comment: As you have posted no code it is difficult to know exactly what you want. I have posted enough to get you started. You should try and figure the rest out for yourself

Answer (score 0):

One way: using `String.Substring` and `Enumerable.All` with [`Char.IsLetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) /[`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isdigit(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim isValid = number.Length = 7
If isValid Then isValid = number.Substring(0, 2).All(AddressOf Char.IsLetter)
If isValid Then isValid = number.Substring(2, 2).All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit)
If isValid Then isValid = number.Substring(4, 3).All(AddressOf Char.IsLetter)
```